# batch file for sporadic internet connection

Tags: file, batch-file, ping, reconnect

i've seen pingers and auto redials when theres a request time out.

problem:
but im having a hard time researching the 'counter or increment' part.

idea:
heres how it should be:

**start pinging continuously while connected to internet,
otherwise
count (or accumulate) request time out until 1min or 60 request time out, 
if connection went back after request time out & less than '60 times request time out',reset the 
'request time out counter' to zero
if request time out reached 60x :
run another batch or reconnect re-dial up.
loop to internet connection pinging**

the closest that i saw:
(but for some reason its not working on my xp)

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:loop

ping -n 2 10.174.10.48 >> log
find /i "Reply" < log > nul
if not errorlevel 1 type nul > log & goto :loop

for /f "tokens=1" %%a in ('find /c /i "Request timed out" ^< log') do (
if %%a geq 10 echo file.exe && type nul > log
)
goto :loop
```

source: http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/ping-bat-file/16605.html

credits to the original poster.
thank you

Comment: Your requirements in bold a hard to decipher. The script you posted only echo's a string and writes NUL to a log file.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to know why the above script is not working. Because possibly other solutions will also not work. If you use a non-English version of windows, you need to replace the text "Reply".

I think the following should work. It just implements the counter. But you can try yourself how you need to set the counter to execute the script after 60 seconds.

```
@echo off

:reset
set count=0
:loop

ping -n 2 10.174.10.48 | find /i "Reply"  
if not errorlevel 1 goto :reset

set /A count=%count%+1
if %count% lss 100 got :loop

call reconnect

goto :reset
```